# I am trying to fetch messages from databse in larvavel (little stuck)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, controller

I am tying to make a chat app in laravel. I am trying to fetch one to one messages.

**Heres my controller:-**

```
public function user( $id) {

        $chat = User::find($id);
        

        $table = DB::table('messages')
        ->where('sender', Auth::user()->id, '&&', 'reciever', $id)
        ->orWhere('sender', $id, '&&', 'reciever', Auth::user()->id)
        ->get();

        return view('user', compact('chat', 'id', 'table'));
   }
```

**My messages Migration:-**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('sender')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('reciever')->unsigned();
            $table->text('message');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Here's the route:-** `Route::get('/user/{id}', 'ContactsController@user');`

**This is the error that I am getting:-**
`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ""sender"": syntax error (SQL: select * from "messages" where reciever "sender" = 30 "sender" = 1)`

I think there is something wrong with my logic, can anyone guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:-

```
$messages = Message::where('sender', $id)->orWhere('reciever', $id)->get();
    $messages = Message::where(function($q) use ($id) {
        $q->where('sender', auth()->id());
        $q->where('reciever', $id);
    })->orWhere(function($q) use ($id){

        $q->where('sender', $id);
        $q->where('reciever', auth()->id());
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#parameter-grouping for information on query groupings. You need to separate out your logic like this

```
$table = DB::table('messages')
    ->where(function($query) use ($id) { // Where (sender = User AND receiver = id)
           $query->where('sender', Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('reciever', $id);
        })
    ->orWhere(function($query) use ($id) { // OR (sender = id AND receiver = User)
           $query->where('sender', $id)
                ->where('reciever', Auth::user()->id);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: this results to `Illuminate\Support\Collection {#281 ▼`
  `#items: []`
`}`  but ill check docks as well, but can you tell me what does that "function" in `orWhere` do

Comment: The function is called a [Closure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php). Passing closures into the where/orWhere creates the query groups that databases need to section off the where clause logic when mixing AND/OR like this one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `where()` and `orWhere()`

```php
->where('sender', Auth::user()->id, '&&', 'reciever', $id)
        ->orWhere('sender', $id, '&&', 'reciever', Auth::user()->id)
```

What you should do instead:

```php
->where([
    ['sender', Auth::user()->id],
    ['reciever', $id],
])->orWhere([
    ['sender', $id],
    ['reciever', Auth::user()->id],
])
```

I suggest reading [Laravel Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses) docs before diving in.

Comment: This results to an empty array but ill check the docs a well

Comment: Make sure the expected sql query was executed & make sure expected records are in the database